# cookies and url check for redirect using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to do a site first time redirect 
So that all user visiting my site washout cookie have been redirected to promo page
Decided to do this by using mod_rewrite from apache

I have done like this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !first-time=true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://promo.mysite.com/ [CO=first-time:true:.mysite.com:43200:/,R,L]
```

And this one is working great, but after some time I found out that my paypal notify page is being unavailable for PayPal, so I need to exclude it from my redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/paypal/notify
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !first-time=true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://promo.mysite.com/ [CO=first-time:true:.mysite.com:43200:/,R,L]
```

But it is not working and I have no idea why 
Can you help me?

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: @Danik: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Be aware that not all users will accept cookies (and not just normal users, but also search engine bots) - so in that case they might never be able to reach your real page.

Comment: I am checking in my browser in incognito mode and it's redirecting me for the first time and not redirecting for the second. the problem is that trying url http://mysite.com/paypal/notify redirecting the same for the first time and not doing this for the second, but according to my rules it should not redirect me for the first time. To be sure that it is not cache problem I have tried wget and it's redirecting too.